# Timed out waiting for response to id, name:"visit","args

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

First, I am aware of the fact that there are multiple questions asked about the same issue. However, I cannot seem to fix this with the suggested answers on those questions. I've tried:

- expect(page).to have_content
- Capybara.reset_sessions!
- page.driver.reset!
- Increased sleep time
- Updated all the gems

None of these solutions appear to have an effect. The first couple of times running these hooks headless it runs fine, it is after the third time these TimeOuts start. Are there any other options I could try?

> Timed out waiting for response to {"id":"9b2de783-a6bc-4fc6-a0a2-1a0e17ead8b2","name":"visit","args":["http://test.com/login",30]}. It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker. (Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError)
>   ./features/support/hooks.rb:10:in `Before'

Hook code:

```
$portal = 'http://test.com'

Before do |scenario|
  if Capybara.javascript_driver == :selenium
    page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize
    end
end

Before('@portal_page_is_open') do
  visit "#{$portal}/login"
  expect(page).to have_content("Log in")
end

Before('@superuser_is_logged_in') do
  fill_in '_username', :with => 'testsuperuser'
  fill_in '_password', :with => 'Test1234'
    click_on 'Log in'
  sleep(5)
end

Before('@player_is_found') do
  expect(page).to have_content("Hi testsuperuser")
  advanced_search = find('#playerSearch > div > div.pull-right > button.advanced-search.btn.btn-link.btn-small')
  advanced_search.click
  sleep(5)
  fill_in 'playerSearch[customerSearch][firstName]', :with => $first_name
  fill_in 'playerSearch[customerSearch][surname]', :with => $last_name
  fill_in 'playerSearch[customerSearch][dateOfBirth]', :with => $date_of_birth
  sleep(1)
  click_on 'Search'
  until page.has_no_content?('Processing request...')
    sleep(5)
  end
end

After do |scenario|
  Cucumber.wants_to_quit = true if scenario.failed?
  Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.default_driver
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
  sleep(10)
end
```

Timeout settings:

```
   Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {debug: false})
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, timeout: 120)
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {js_errors: false})
 end
```

Gem list:

```
ruby "2.3.3"
gem "rdoc", "6.0.1"
gem "rspec", "3.7.0"
gem "capybara", "2.17.0"
gem "cucumber", "3.1.0"
gem "selenium-webdriver", "3.8.0"
gem "chronic", "0.10.2"
gem "poltergeist", "1.17.0"
gem "pg", "1.0.0"
gem "rest-client", "2.0.0"
gem "stomp", "1.4.4"
gem "net-ssh", "3.2.0"
gem "net-scp", "1.2.1"
gem "savon", "2.11.1"
gem "json"
gem "rake"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was a JSphantom error pop up that occurred when running the test headless.

Adding: `page.driver.restart if defined?(page.driver.restart)` to the after hook solved the issue.